# Evaluation of expression fmap (*3) (+5) 1

Tags: haskell

Could you please help me verify evaluation of following Haskell expression: fmap (*3) (+5) 1 ?  I struggle especially with the correct parsing of the fmap x y z.

Thank you

My trial:

```
fmap (*3) (+5) 1 -- nothing to do 1 is 1
=> (fmap (*3)) (+5) 1 -- function application infixl 10
=> ((fmap (*3)) (+5)) 1 -- function application infixl 10
=> ((fmap (*3) (+5)) 1 -- (f (x) y) equivalent to (f x y)
=> ((*3) . (+5)) 1 -- fmap f g = f.g; 
=> (*3) ((+5) 1) -- (f.g) x = f (g x) 
=> (*3) 6 
=> 18
```

Comment: From a quick glance, your evaluation looks correct -- in particular, replacing `fmap` with its definition for the function instance in the fourth step is the right thing to do. Do you have some more specific question about it?

Comment: It looks correct.

Answer (score 7):

The reasoning you demonstrate seems *correct*.

We can make a more rigorous answer on how Haskell does it. First the type checker will be activated.

Haskell sees the expression

```
((fmap (*3)) (+5)) 1
```

So first it does some type reasoning:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(*3) :: Num c => c -> c
(+5) :: Num d => d -> d
1 :: Num e => e
```

Since we call `fmap` with `(*3)` this thus means that `a -> b ~ c -> c`, and thus `a ~ b ~ c`, so we get:

```
fmap :: (Num a, Functor f) => (a -> a) -> f a -> f a
(*3) :: Num a => a -> a
(+5) :: Num d => d -> d
1 :: Num e => e
```

So that means that `fmap (*3)` has type `fmap (*3) :: (Num a, Functor f) => f a -> f a`. Since `(+5) :: Num d => d -> d` is the argument of that function, we see that `f a ~ d -> d`. Or in a more canonical form: `f a ~ (->) d d`. So that means that `f ~ (-> d)` and `a ~ d`. This holds since there is  `Functor` for `(->) a`:

> ```
> instance Functor ((->) a) where
>     fmap = (.)
> ```

So we now have types:

```
fmap :: Num a => (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
fmap :: Num a => (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
fmap = (.)
(*3) :: Num a => a -> a
(+5) :: Num a => a -> a
1 :: Num e -> e
```

So that means that `fmap (*3) (+5)` has type `(->) a a`. We call this function with `1`, so that means that `e ~ a`, so:

```
fmap :: Num a => (a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
fmap = (.)
(*3) :: Num a => a -> a
(+5) :: Num a => a -> a
1 :: Num a -> a
```

So now we type checked the function, and we came to the conclusion that `fmap = (.)`, so we have basically written:

```
(((.) (*3)) (+5)) 1
```

And now if we want to evaluate this, we get:

```
   (((.) (*3)) (+5)) 1
-> (*3) ((+5) 1)
-> (*3) 6
-> 18
```

Comment: Additionally, the constant `1` expands to `fromIntegral (1::Integer)`, defaulting to `Integer`, which is indeed an instance of `Num`.  So, `a` is `Integer` here.

Comment: Thank you very much for great detail explanation Willem.